# Questions on express session not working in AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I am new to AWS. Recently, I have been trying to move one of my project's frontend and backend to AWS. I moved the backend to elastic beanstalk first. Everything is working well except the session.
The problem is that the session will be lost if I refresh the website.
I am not sure if I missed something on the session setup since it is working well in heroku.
There is one thing I am not sure is the url of the backend in elastic beanstalk. It starts with http instead of https. I have read solutions in other similar questions but none of them helped.
The code below is the session setup.

```
app.use(session({
resave: false, 
saveUninitialized: false, 
secret: 'my secret',
proxy: true,
cookie: {
    secure: true,
    sameSite: "None"
}

}));
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
```

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

The session needs to be saved persistently. You need to use a session store with persistence, (ie mongodb, MySQL,etc). Your code now is just saving it in the browser temporarily.      [You can check the documentation for compatible stores.](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html#compatible-session-stores)